# Can I have favourite pages?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I regulary use specifially pages in OneNote. They are organized in different notebooks so I have to click twice or three times to open this site - finding the right.

Is it possible to link these pages and have them as favourites somewhere, e. g. in the head or in a sidebar or somewhere else?

Having an favourite page with links to the other pages is not a solution because I have to switch to this page, too.

Answer (score 0):

OneNote does not have native favorites support. There is a OneNote plugin called Onetastic that adds this feature.

Onetastic: https://getonetastic.com/

Favorites feature information: https://getonetastic.com/how-to/favorites

Answer (score 0):

I have a section at the top-level of my hierarchy called Links. I use that as my favorites, and I can put different pages in the section for groups of favorites. Then on each page, I just copy the link to my favorite pages. To do this:

- Navigate to the page you want to "favorite."
- Right-click on the page name in the right margin and select *Copy link to page*.
- Navigate to your links/favorite page and paste the link.
- You can even change the text that displays on the link if you want